# What is the difference between SignalR and OneSignal?

Tags: asp.net-core, xamarin.forms, signalr, real-time, onesignal

I'm developing a mobile app using `Xamarin forms`. There I cache data obtained from some endpoints. Now, if an item updated from another device, I have to clear the cache and obtain the new data.So, I have to make my app `real-time`. the backend implementation is done with `SignalR`. I searched "signalr xamarin sdk" in youtube the first video appeared is [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AlqZ1LpUXeg). However, when searched the same in Bing, I got [this link](https://www.bing.com/ck/a?!&&p=13245f89a09c4009JmltdHM9MTY2NTAxNDQwMCZpZ3VpZD0yOGJjZTBjZS1hMmU2LTY3ZWYtMjE0ZS1mMGJhYTZlNjYxMTYmaW5zaWQ9NTE4Mw&ptn=3&hsh=3&fclid=28bce0ce-a2e6-67ef-214e-f0baa6e66116&psq=signalr%20xamarin%20sdk&u=a1aHR0cHM6Ly9kb2N1bWVudGF0aW9uLm9uZXNpZ25hbC5jb20vZG9jcy94YW1hcmluLXNkay1zZXR1cA&ntb=1). That's why I got confused. can anyone clarify this?

Comment: They are two different companies that provide kind off similar products...

Comment: Which one would you prefer?

Comment: Depends on your requirement and who fulfils it better to be honest

Answer (score 1):

Basically SignalR is a .NET library for handling real-time communication between your server and your client, over WebSockets for example but not only.

I use it in my ASP.NET server [aspnet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/introduction?view=aspnetcore-6.0) and my Xamarin app [tutorial](https://mindofai.github.io/Building-a-Real-Time-Chat-App-With-SignalR-and-Xamarin/). It's really simple to adopt it in your own .NET system.

I don't know OneSignal but from the main page documentation [documentation](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/onesignal-platform) it seems to be more focused on server to client notifications like push notification, email, sms and so on.